# I want to perform Aggregate function on multiple columns of specified schema in SQL

Tags: java, php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to perform the average operation on the multiple columns of a table to get the percentage of attendance of students with having a range between start and end date.


Columns are Date and roll numbers 1(present) and 0(absent)

```
Date        01  02  03  04  05
==============================
2015-12-09  1   0   1   0   1
2015-12-10  0   1   0   1   1
2015-12-11  1   1   1   1   0
2015-12-12  0   0   0   1   1
2015-12-13  1   0   1   1   0
```

How this can be achieved using PHP or Java.

Comment: I'd like to see it solved with your Android tag personally.

Comment: I guess you would need SQL to solve this one

Comment: Roll numbers? Eh?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Ohh thanks, man.Thanks for the value-added information.@AlexZen